# Storage of a Baofeng UV-5R

Tags: uv-5r, baofeng, battery

I am trying to find a convenient place to store my Baofeng UV-5R, I believe the most convenient place to store it would be on its charger.

I was wondering if storing the UV-5R with its battery still installed, on the unplugged charger with its wall-wart power supply removed would drain the battery or have any negative effect on it.

Comment: What kind of storage?  If it is long-term, then the switch should be off and it should not be in the charger stand.  But to have handy for usage you would want the charger plugged in.  So you might want to edit your question to clarify what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries) has some general information on storing batteries. Relevant points:

- Storing a Li-ion battery in a discharged state will permanently damage it
- Storing a Li-ion battery at 100% charge is less than optimal
- around 40% charge is optimal for storage
- Lower temperatures are better
- Freezing is bad

Leaving the battery connected to the radio or the charger might discharge it slowly due to leakage currents. Normally manufacturers try to minimize this, but there is always some leakage in solid-state devices. Given the cheapness of Baofeng, I doubt they put much engineering into this aspect.

Given that cold temperatures are favorable, the refrigerator would be a good place. Put in in a sealed, heavy plastic bag to buffer against moisture. To avoid problems with condensation, don't open the bag or use the battery until it's had time to come back to ambient temperature. Definitely avoid any place in the sun or that gets hot like a car.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine as long as you don't have it plugged in. If you have it plugged in it makes a lot of noise and it is hard to listen to.

Answer (score 1):

Not on the AC charger, certainly. It generates so much noise on VHF/UHF/Commercial FM for me that I cannot listen to it while it's charging. Try using the 12VDC adapter included in the set connected to a PC PSU instead, This worked for me, no noise any more when my UV-5R is docked.

Comment: The OP asked about storing it in the charger with the charger *unplugged.*

Comment: Oh. I guess he wants to store it unplugged because the transformer is so noisy... I store mine plugged.